# Load data on demand - Angular Material autocomplete

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete, angularjs-material

I want to use Angular Material's autocomplete component, but the field is not required and the data is a 3000 object array.

I want to load the data only if the user clicks on the component. So when the user clicks,  I wanted to show a spinner like an async select, make the API call and then load the data.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: Are you using Angular or AngularJS?

Answer (score 0):

There is some documentation on asynchronous:

[`md-autocomplete` async](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdAutocomplete#asynchronous-results)

EDIT: Here's an example:

HTML template:

```html
<md-autocomplete md-selected-item="selectedItem" md-search-text="searchText" md-items="item in query(searchText)">
  <md-item-template>
    <span md-highlight-text="searchText">{{item}}</span>
  </md-item-template>
</md-autocomplete>
```

AngularJS Controller:

```js
function AppController($scope, $http) {
  $scope.query = function(searchText) {
    return $http
      .get('https://example.com/api/myItems/?q=' + searchText)
      .then(function(data) {
        // Map the response object to the data object.
        return data;
    });
};
```

}